# PHP IMAP fetch partial email message from Email service provider

Tags: php, email, imap

Hello I am using PHP IMAP to retrieve emails from various email-service providers like Gmail, Outlook etc

My question is that usually these service providers in every single Email Body send new message at the top along with email-chain(old-messages/conversation) at the end of the email. Now when I try to retrieve individual email message content I see both the new message content as well as entire conversation content, so my question is there anyway I can distinguish between new message content and conversation

Is there anyway I can use PHP IMAP to find out the new message content in a single email

PS:-
When I say conversation-content I am referring to the entire Email Conversation that gets appended automatically at the end of every email

Comment: There is no standard for this, so in general, no. You would have to do significant text processing and use heuristic techniques to do this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903497/getting-only-the-reply-from-imap-message